# Error while trying to decompress stream in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, deflatestream

I'm trying to decompress a stream from a PDF Object in this [file](https://eternal-todo.com/files/pdf/myPDF_flatedecode.pdf):

```
 4 0 obj
<< 
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 64
>>
stream
xœs
QÐw34V02UIS0´0P030PIQÐpÉÏKIUH-.ITH.-*Ê··×TÉRp
á T‰
Ê
endstream
endobj
```

I have this stream copy-pasted with the same format as in the original file in a file called `Stream.file`

```
xœs
QÐw34V02UIS0´0P030PIQÐpÉÏKIUH-.ITH.-*Ê··×TÉRp
á T‰
Ê
```

This stream should translate to: `Donde esta curro??`. Added that stream to a `Stream.file` in a C# Console application.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace Filters
{
    public static class FiltersLoader
    {
        public static void Parse()
        {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Stream.file");
            var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

            using (var decompressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

However it yields an exception whil trying to copy it:

`The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.`

I'd like how to decode this stream with .net code if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't copy-paste binary data is if it were text and expect this to go smoothly. There are many things that can go wrong there, even if by some stroke of luck you use an encoding that contains single code points all the characters. You'll need to be a little more wily and write a little program to read the file until it gets to the `>>stream` (or just try until you get the offset right) and extract the bytes as true binary content. (That's aside from whether you can actually use `DeflateStream` here; I don't know PDF well enough to say if that's right.)

Comment: You were partly right, I didn't realize while copying it added Windows return lines, but after changing it to Unix LF and making sure both streams look the same in https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/ and still having the same issue.

Comment: Error message seems pretty self-explanatory to me. You are trying to decompress data that the `DeflateStream()` class does not recognize as a supported compression method. Either the data is corrupted or it uses a different compression method.

Comment: Hi, I see that too. However as you can see from the PDF file I took the stream from it was compressed one time using the FlateDecode algorithm, that it's the same I'm using in c# while trying to decompress it (Deflate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that the `DeflateStream` class can decode a naked FLATE compressed stream (as per [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951)) but the content of PDF streams with **FlateDecode** filter actually is presented in the ZLIB Compressed Data Format (as per [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950)) *wrapping* FLATE compressed data.

To fix this it suffices to drop the two-byte ZLIB header.

Another problem became clear in your first example document: That document was encrypted, so before FLATE decoding the stream contents therein have to be decrypted.

###Drop ZLIB header to get to the FLATE encoded data

The `DeflateStream` class can decode a naked FLATE compressed stream (as per [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951)) but the content of PDF streams with **FlateDecode** filter actually is presented in the ZLIB Compressed Data Format (as per [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950)) *wrapping* FLATE compressed data.

Fortunately it is pretty easy to jump to the FLATE encoded data therein, one simply has to drop the first two bytes. (Strictly speaking there might be a *dictionary identifier* between them and the FLATE encoded data but this appears to be seldom used.)

in case of your code:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Stream.file");
var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

originalFileStream.ReadByte();
originalFileStream.ReadByte();

using (var decompressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
}
```

###In case of encrypted PDFs, decrypt first

Your first example file [pdf-test.pdf](http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf) is encrypted as is indicated by the presence of an **Encrypt** entry in the trailer:

```
trailer
<</Size 37/Encrypt 38 0 R>>
startxref
116
%%EOF
```

Before decompressing stream contents, therefore, you have to decrypt them.

Comment: This is the trailer: trailer
<</Size 7
/Root 1 0 R 
>> and it doesn't show the Encrypt object.

Comment: That may be the trailer after you changed your question to refer to a completely different test file. Please don't make your question such a moving target.

Comment: I couldn't locate the previous file, that's why I changed it to a easier file. but the problem is the same.

Comment: Please share the new file. Dumping binary data as text most likely damages it.

Comment: Sorry for changing the file, this is the latest: https://eternal-todo.com/files/pdf/myPDF_flatedecode.pdf

Comment: if you open the stream on HxD you'll see it starts with `78 9C` which is the start of a header of a valid Deflate Stream

Comment: `78 01 - No Compression/low
78 9C - Default Compression
78 DA - Best Compression `

Comment: That PDF is broken (a hint is that after opening it in Adobe Reader and closing it again, Adobe Reader asks whether it should be saved). In particular your example stream is damaged, it claims a size of 64 bytes but only is 60 or 61 bytes in size.

Comment: You are right on the size, but in case there is a mismatch you should follow the stream length instead. I'm opening that file in Adobe and doesn't complain with any errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and the detailed explanation, it really helped.