# Cross reference stream decoding

Tags: pdf

I wrote a pdf parser with my own Deflate decoder. It works fine for all streams contents I encountered up to now, but it fails to decode the binary contents of a xref stream. Here are, in hexadecimal format, the bytes found after "stream" and before "endstream" :

68 DE 62 62 62 60 D8 CB F4 9F 79 F5 1F 20 83 A9 19 48 F0 AB 01 
09 86 E9 00 01 06 00 46 3B 04 C4

After dropping the first two bytes (zlib header 0x68 0xDE), my Deflate decoder reads 26 bytes and stops, having produced 34 bytes on output :

02 02 00 00 BD 02 FF 03 AB FC 02 00 00 02 83 02
00 00 02 83 02 FF 26 02 83 O2 0F 26 02 83 02 0F
00 97

Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BHB0AAdAVA6EQuE-aPHrCXvdqU8uUWFP

The /Filter entry in the stream dictionary is set to /FlateDecode and, as far as I can see, this file is not encrypted. There is also a /DecodeParms entry set to a dictionary containing /Columns 4 /Predictor 12, but, if I'm right, it must be used after inflating the stream binary data.

The Deflate decoder produces 34 bytes on output but, even after applying a PNG Up filter, they don't make sense to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the full PDF file you are talking about.

Comment: Did my answer clear up the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

FLATE decoding that stream results in

```
02 02 00 00 BD 02 FF 03 AB FC 02 00 00 02 83 02 00 00 0F 26 02 00 00 00 97
```

Thus, your claim *The Deflate decoder produces 34 bytes* indicates that you are doing something wrong using your Deflate decoder.

Have you considered that PDF FLATE encoded streams do not contain the *naked* FLATE compressed data but instead are in the ZLIB Compressed Data Format *wrapping* FLATE compressed data? If your decoder expects the naked data, you first have to drop the ZLIB header. For details and references see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58199465/1729265).

To finalize the decoding we have to resolve the PNG Up predictor use:

```
02 02 00 00 BD         02 00 00 BD
02 FF 03 AB FC         01 03 AB B9
02 00 00 02 83   -->   01 03 AD 3C
02 00 00 0F 26         01 03 BC 62
02 00 00 00 97         01 03 BC F9
```

Considering `/Index[185 2 188 3]` and `/W[1 3 0]`, therefore:

- Object 185 is in object stream 189
- Object 186 starts at offset 0x03ABB9
- Object 188 starts at offset 0x03AD3C
- Object 189 starts at offset 0x03BC62
- Object 190 starts at offset 0x03BCF9